# What are some good solutions for testing in ie6?

Tags: asp.net, testing, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

Unfortunately I still have to support ie6.  I currently don't have a machine with ie6 on it any longer and would like to here what you all use.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a [virtual machine](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) with XP on it and run IE6 in there!

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Expression Web Super Preview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874) is one way to test.  It only lets you view one page at a time but it's something.

Ideally, I'd get yourself a machin with IE6 on it or install a virtual machine on your box with IE6 loaded onto it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:
1 Use a virtual machine like virtualbox or vmware
  I think this is a better way, though it takes more time...
2 use some software like ietest

Answer (score 1):

You can try IETester ([Website](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage))